# p:dataTable add class to row on cellEdit

Tags: primefaces

In a `p:dataTable` I have rowStyleCalss

```
rowStyleClass="#{field.version eq -1 ? 'draft' : null}"
```

but it don't work when data are edited. I need then reload page which is bad idea when user edit one row.
When user finish editing *field.version* is set to -1. I want to add class 'draft' to row then.

Can you help me with that?

Comment: use PrimeFaces extensions `pe:javascript` to add a class to the row on the start of the edit event and remove it when editing is done

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function handleCellEdit(args)
        {
            if(! ($("tr[data-ri='"+args.rowIndex+"']").hasClass('draft'))) {
                $("tr[data-ri='"+args.rowIndex+"']").addClass('draft')
            }
        }
    </script>


<p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="....." oncomplete="handleCellEdit(args);" />
```

In onCellEdit method in bean

```
RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
requestContext.addCallbackParam("rowIndex", event.getRowIndex());
```